# WPF: TreeViewItem bound to an ICommand

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, command, icommand

I am busy creating my first MVVM application in WPF.

Basically the problem I am having is that I have a TreeView (System.Windows.Controls.TreeView) which I have placed on my WPF Window, I have decide that I will bind to a ReadOnlyCollection of CommandViewModel items, and these items consist of a DisplayString, Tag and a RelayCommand.

Now in the XAML, I have my TreeView and I have successfully bound my ReadOnlyCollection to this. I can view this and everything looks fine in the UI.

The issue now is that I need to bind the RelayCommand to the Command of the TreeViewItem, however from what I can see the TreeViewItem doesn't have a Command. Does this force me to do it in the IsSelected property or even in the Code behind TreeView_SelectedItemChanged method or is there a way to do this magically in WPF?

This is the code I have:

```
<TreeView BorderBrush="{x:Null}" 
      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
      VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
<TreeView.Items>
    <TreeViewItem
        Header="New Commands"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Commands}"
        DisplayMemberPath="DisplayName"
        IsExpanded="True">
    </TreeViewItem>
</TreeView.Items>
```

and ideally I would love to just go:

```
<TreeView BorderBrush="{x:Null}" 
      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
      VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
<TreeView.Items>
    <TreeViewItem
        Header="New Trade"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Commands}"
        DisplayMemberPath="DisplayName"
        IsExpanded="True"
        Command="{Binding Path=Command}">
    </TreeViewItem>
</TreeView.Items>
```

Does someone have a solution that allows me to use the RelayCommand infrastructure I have.

Thanks guys, much appreciated!

Richard

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I know this was "answered" a while ago, but since the answers weren't ideal, I figured I'd put in my two cents.  I use a method that allows me to not have to resort to any "styled button trickery" or even using code-behind and instead keeps all my separation in MVVM.  In your TreeView add the following xaml:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectedItemChanged">
        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding TreeviewSelectedItemChanged}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=treeView, Path=SelectedItem}"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

In your xaml header add:

```
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
```

and then you'll have to add a reference to the above assembly in your project.

After that, everything acts just the same as any other command would on say a button or something.

Comment: +1 - This is a great answer since it's not a code-behind solution. However, this isn't an out-of-the box solution :(.

Comment: Is `System.Windows.Interactivity` redistributable?

Comment: Yes, see "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Expression\Blend\.NETFramework\v4.0\Redist.en.txt".

Comment: For those who do not want to use Blend, just create a behavior.

Comment: A "Thinking out-of-the box" solution perhaps? :)

Comment: You can use nuget to get these libraries

Comment: You can just add a reference from the GAC in Visual Studio, you do not need to use Blend. -- Since the DLL is referenced, it will automatically be included in your installer (assuming you're using a regular installer project, or ClickOnce).

Comment: @Shaggy13spe Could you please show a usage example on the actual `TreeViewItem`?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the input into the issue, and yes, I did say I didn't want a Code behind solution, however at that time I was still very much under the impression that I was simply missing something... so I ended up using the TreeView_SelectedItemChanged event.

Even though Will's approach seems like a good work around, for my personal situation I decided that I would use the code behind. The reason for this is so that the View and XAML would remain as it would be if the TreeViewItem had a "Command" property to which my Command could be bound. Now I do not have to change the Templates or the Views, all I have to do is add the code and the Event for the TreeView_SelectedItemChanged.

My solution:

```
  private void TreeView_SelectedItemChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
    {
        if (sender != null)
        {
            var treeView = sender as TreeView;
            if (treeView != null)
            {
                var commandViewModel = treeView.SelectedItem as CommandViewModel;
                if (commandViewModel != null)
                {
                    var mi = commandViewModel.Command.GetType().GetMethod("Execute");
                    mi.Invoke(commandViewModel.Command, new Object[] {null});
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

As I already have the RelayCommand attached to the TreeViewItem, all I am now doing is to just manually invoke the "Execute" method on that specific RelayCommand.

If this is the completely wrong way of going about it then please let me know...

Thanks!

Comment: I believe with the ASP.NET treeview you can extend TreeView and TreeViewItem to add this kind of functionality.  You'd change the TVI to add what you needed and then overrode a method in TV to create a new instance of your TVI.  I don't know if the same pattern is available in the WPF treeview; I checked but not that thoroughly.

Answer (score 1):

What I'd do is set [the Header](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.headereditemscontrol.header(VS.100).aspx) of the TreeViewItem to be a button, then skin the button so that it doesn't look or act like one, then perform my command binding against the button.

You might need to do this via a DataTemplate, or you might need to change the template of the TreeViewItem itself.  Never done it, but this is how I've done similar things (such as tab page headers).

---

Here's an example of what I'm talking about (you can drop this in Kaxaml and play around with it):

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
   <Page.Resources>
      <Style x:Key="ClearButan" TargetType="Button">
         <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
               <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">              
                 <Border Name="border"
                     Padding="4"
                     Background="transparent">
                     <Grid >
                     <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Center">
                     </ContentPresenter>
                     </Grid>
                 </Border>
               </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
         </Setter>
      </Style>
   </Page.Resources>
   <Grid>
      <TreeView>
         <TreeViewItem>
            <Button Style="{StaticResource ClearButan}">
            easy peasy
            </Button>
         </TreeViewItem>
      </TreeView>
   </Grid>
</Page>
```

I've created a new clear style for a button.  I then just drop a button in the TVI and set its style.  You can do the same thing using data templates, of course.

Comment: Hi, I see what you're trying to do, and appreciate the quick response, but is this really the best solution? I have searched the net high and low and can't find a nice way of doing it! Have to say its annoying that this isn't just built in. 

But at least you've provided a way of doing this, but now how do you get the header to show the button, and the bound text?

Comment: Thanks Will for the update and I see that this would probably work. I have gone a different route, but very much appreciate the help. Hopefully this will help someone else who has this issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good example of how the MVVM is very much an after-thought in WPF. You expect there to be Command support of certain gui items, but there isn't, so you're forced to go through an elaborate process (as shown in Will's example) just to get a command attached to something.

Let's hope they address this in WPF 2.0 :-)

Comment: MVVM came after WPF, so it wasn't exactly an "afterthought", it was a way to apply the principles of MVC to WPF.  Also, this is more of a shortcoming of the treeview that WPF.  The treeview wasn't developed for this kind of use, which was kinda short sighted imho.

Answer (score 0):

I improve good solution from [Richard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/273605/richard)  via common Tag property:

MyView.xaml:

```
 <TreeView SelectedItemChanged="TreeView_SelectedItemChanged" Tag="{Binding SelectTreeViewCommand}" >
                  <TreeViewItem Header="Item1" IsExpanded="True"   Tag="Item1"  />
                  <TreeViewItem Header="Item2" IsExpanded="True">
                      <TreeViewItem Header="Item21"  Tag="Item21"/>
                  </TreeViewItem>
              </TreeView>
```

---

MyView.xaml.cs

```
    private void TreeView_SelectedItemChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
    {
        var treeView = (TreeView)sender;
        var command = (ICommand)treeView.Tag;
        TreeViewItem selectedItem = (TreeViewItem)treeView.SelectedItem;
        if (selectedItem.Tag != null)
        {
            command.Execute(selectedItem.Tag);
        }
    }
```

---

MyViewModel.cs

```
      public RelayCommand selectTreeViewCommand;
      [Bindable(true)]
      public RelayCommand SelectTreeViewCommand => selectTreeViewCommand ?? (selectTreeViewCommand = new RelayCommand(CanSelectTreeViewCommand, ExecuteSelectTreeViewCommand));

      private void ExecuteSelectTreeViewCommand(object obj)
      {
          Console.WriteLine(obj);
      }

      private bool CanSelectTreeViewCommand(object obj)
      {
          return true;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided by Shaggy13spe is very good. But still, it took me some additional time to understand it so I will extend the answer.

Whole TreeView xaml can look like this:

```cs
<TreeView x:Name="treeView" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Tree}">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectedItemChanged">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding FilterMeetingsCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding  ElementName=treeView, Path=SelectedItem}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Nodes}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Id}"></TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

In my View I have a **Tree** collection

```cs
public ObservableCollection<TreeNode> Tree { get; set; }
```

**TreeNode** is defined as a simple class:

```cs
public class TreeNode
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<TreeNode> Nodes { get; set; }

    public TreeNode(string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Nodes = new List<TreeNode>();
    }
}
```

First important point: **CommandParameter** is not bind to the property on the ViewModel but it is passed to the method. So the method should look like:

```cs
private async void FilterMeeting(object parameter){}
```

Second important point: if you will pass the selected item (in my case object will be **TreeNode** type) and you will have the hierarchical structure you will face event bubbling. So selecting an item will fire the event for this particular item and for all parents. To resolve this you need to understand that you can pass only one object to the method in **ViewModel** (not two as in standard event handler) and this object needs to be an event.

In this case change the XAML to following (**PassEventArgsToCommand="True"** is important here)

```cs
<TreeView x:Name="treeView" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Tree}">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectedItemChanged">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding FilterMeetingsCommand}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Nodes}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Id}"></TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

Then in your handling method, you won't receive the model object, but event args, which have a model object inside.

[image: Event with selected element]