# mvvm navigation treeview

Tags: wpf, mvvm, treeview

i'm trying to implement a navigation menu using a treeview.
on the left panel there is a treeview and on the right panel the matched view.
since it's MVVM i'm having a difficult to switch between the correct views.

[image]

clicking on Menu1 - should display View1.xaml view
clicking on Menu2 - should display View2.xaml view

my code looks like that:
MainView.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="Menu.View.MainView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:Views="clr-namespace:Menu.View"
        Title="MainView" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Views:Page1}">
            <Views:Page1 />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Views:Page2}">
            <Views:Page2 />
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <DockPanel>
        <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Left">
            <TreeView>
                <TreeViewItem Header="Menu 1" />
                <TreeViewItem Header="Menu 2" />
                <TreeViewItem Header="Menu 3" />
            </TreeView>
        </Grid>

        <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Right">
                <Views:Page1 />
                <Views:Page2 />
        </Grid>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Page1.xaml (the view that should be visible when clicking "Menu 1")

```
<Grid>
    <Label FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold">1</Label>
</Grid>
```

Page2.xaml (the view that should be visible when clicking "Menu 2")

```
<Grid>
    <Label FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold">2</Label>
</Grid>
```

for every page i have its own ViewModel and i have the main one called MainViewModel.
how should i implement such thing in a MVVM mode ?

Answer (score 0):

I think here is the mistake. You should have put your ViewModels in the DataType. so when you fill the DataContext the DataTemplate do his job. something like :

```
   <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:Page1ViewModel}">
                <Views:Page1 />
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:Page2ViewModel}">
                <Views:Page2 />
            </DataTemplate>
```

instead of :

```
<Views:Page1 />
<Views:Page2 />
```

add a ContentControl and do a binding to it's content like this :

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding MyViewModel}"></ContentControl>
```

myView is property in your MainViewViewModel ([which has to implement INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695.aspx)) can be like this :

```
        object _MyView;
        public object MyViewModel
        {
            get
            {
                return _MyView;
            }
            set
            {
                _MyView = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("MyViewModel");
            }
        }
```

now, in each TreeViewItem add a [Command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2266890/wpf-treeviewitem-bound-to-an-icommand) that do update it's Content for ex :

in your MainViewViewModel add CallView1Command property and implement it [(see how dealing with commands)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/274982/Commands-in-MVVM)

so in Command's excute method you can update MyViewModel according to the View you want to show.

I recommend using **[Unity](http://unity.codeplex.com/)** to instanciate ViewModels.

Not very well explained, but, Hope it helps anyway

Comment: still... how can u make the choice of the visible View ?

Comment: Answer Updated ! MVVM is kind a lot of work for few functionalities, but it's worth it.

Comment: hi, i appreciate your answer. and this is why i still insist doing it with MVVM.
i don't understand the last part of your answer.
Command property doesn't exist for TreeViewItem.
if you can demonstrate selection of the desired view i will appreciate that very much.

Comment: i'll post my implementation later on... i think there's a better and pretty way to do it.

Comment: I'm sorry it was a mistake about commands in treeviewitem but you can always work arround take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2266890/wpf-treeviewitem-bound-to-an-icommand)